# How to store signature as an image in firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I have a form, in that form I have a signature pad. I used signature 3.2.0 package. That package consist a method toImage(). I want to store that image in the firebase storage. when I try below code.

```
fileImage = _controller.toImage() as File;
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final String picture = "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
StorageUploadTask task = storage.ref().child(picture).putFile(fileImage);
task.onComplete.then((snapshot) async{
   loadData.setSignatureURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
loadData.storeDetails();
```

I got an error *type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast*.
How can I store signature as an image/

Comment: In line one you have the as File typecast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting can't be done on a whim, which is why you get this error.

The `Image` class provides a `toByteData` method that allows you to retrieve the raw image data as a `ByteData` object. You can then convert this to a `Uint8List`. This list then can be directly used for firebase storage with the `putData` method instead of `putFile`.

```dart
var image = await _controller.toImage();

ByteData data = await image.toByteData();
Uint8List listData = data.buffer.asUint8List();

final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final String picture = "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
StorageUploadTask task = storage.ref().child(picture).putData(listData);
...
```

---

If you need to encode this image to a specific type. You can use a version of the following code which encodes to JPG. It uses the [`image`](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package which needs to be added as a dependency

```dart
import 'package:image/image.dart' as encoder;//This import needs to be added in the file this is being done

var image = await _controller.toImage();

//Store image dimensions for later
int height = image.height;
int width = image.width;

ByteData data = await image.toByteData();
Uint8List listData = data.buffer.asUint8List();

encoder.Image toEncodeImage = encoder.Image.fromBytes(width, height, listData);
encoder.JpegEncoder jpgEncoder = encoder.JpegEncoder();

List<int> encodedImage = jpgEncoder.encodeImage(toEncodeImage);

final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final String picture = "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
StorageUploadTask task = storage.ref().child(picture).putData(Uint8List.fromList(encodedImage));
...
```

Comment: now file can be saved, but it cannot be open. Looks like image crashed

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean "cannot be open"? This seems like a separate issue.

Comment: https://ibb.co/SwBmR0R you can see how image has saved

Comment: Nope its saved like a file. Needs to be like https://ibb.co/KV1ZpgG

Comment: @Rahul Do you need to encode the image to JPG? You don't mention that in your question.

Comment: Yes that I want sorry I forget to mention it. How can encode??

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have some small issue after complete getDowloadURL provide different url now. Its works fine early

Comment: @Rahul This is a separate issue. Please accept an answer on this question if it helped and ask a new question.

Comment: What is the solution to show the image later?